# Golang try to Unmarshal array of object

Tags: arrays, json, go

Hello I try to unmarshal the value of array inside a fields of json, but try return empty array I don know the reason why. Can any please help me? here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    type order struct {
        Uid             string              `json:"uid"`
        Name            string              `json:"name"`
                State           string              `json:"state"`
    }
    type Root struct {
    q []order
    }

    s := `{"q":[{"uid":"0x4ecb99b9","name":"Brandon Test Order","state":"draft"}]}`

    var r Root
    ero := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &r)
    if ero != nil {
        fmt.Println("error order")
        fmt.Println(ero)
    }
    fmt.Println("order")
    fmt.Println(r.q)
    return
}
```

here is the output result

```
Hello, playground
order
[]
```

Comment: Fields MUST be exported for them to be unmarshalable. Change `q` to `Q`.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/bTGQYfPr83s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your structs and Json tags are mismatching. Please use following refactored code. You can find working snippet on playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/3z_s2nTvOHT). Also the Orders must be exported.

```golang
    
     type order struct {
        Uid   string `json:"uid"`
        Name  string `json:"name"`
        State string `json:"state"`
    }

    type Root struct {
        Orders []order `json:"q"`
    }
```

Comment: Thank Shailesh. It is working right now

Answer (score 0):

Try this structure

```
type GetOrder struct {
    Orders []struct {
        Uid       string `json:"uid"`
        Name      string `json:"name"`
        State     string `json:"state"`
    } `json:"q"`
}
```